# How precalculate this lighting layer like in this Raycaster Engine

Tags: 3d, rendering, raycasting, lighting

please check this raycaster example be Sage3D: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abki1Tp1maM
I wonder how the lighting layer is done?

For sure it baked into sometinhg, we can see soft shadows, occlusion and colors.

I was tkingking about baking each cell into separate texture, but even for 64x64 cells it would be 4096 textures only for floor, you also need walls and maybbe ceilings so it would.
The second thought was that baking one texture 512x512 for ex. for 100  or 200 cells.

But maybe it is possible to bake the buffer somehow?? please note again that this is software raycaster not poligonal software renderer.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ps. please also note that any "each per-pixel operation" will kill the performance :)

Comment: maybe light map for the floor/ceiling... single 2D image